# When is Chevalley Warning's bound best possible?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, finite-fields

Chevalley Warning's theorem (a form of) states that any homogeneous form over a finite field of degree $d$ in more than $d$ variables has a nontrivial zero in the field. However, for diagonal forms, this result is often much weaker than it needs to be. I am wondering if anyone knows of a particularly good reference on improving the bound for certain families of diagonal forms? I apologize if this is a question better fit for MSE.

Comment: What are you after? There are hundreds of papers on this  topic. A search for diagonal equations over finite fields will show several, e.g. the work of Daqing Wan. Note that $\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} x_i^{p-1}=0$ has only the trivial solution over $\mathbb{F}_p$, $p$ prime, so some assumption is necessary.

Answer (score 6):

Consider a degree $d$ homogeeous diagonal form in $n$ variables over $\mathbb F_q$.

I think that for $d$ quite large this is a problem in additive combinatorics. Essentially you have sets $A_1, \dots, A_n$, each a translate of the set of $d$th powers, and you're trying to show that $0 \in A_1+ \dots + A_n$ nontrivially.

One possible method is Fourier analytic. Without loss of generality $d$ divides $q-1$.  We may write the number of solutions of $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i^{d}=0$ as

$$\frac{1}{q} \sum_{\psi: \mathbb F_q \to \mathbb C^{\times}}\prod_{i=1}^n \left( \sum_{x_i \in \mathbb F_q }\psi( a_i x_i^d) \right)$$

The main term $\psi=1$ is $q^{n-1}$, so to have the other terms smaller and thus guarantee nontrivial solutions we need an estimate for $\psi$ nontrivial:

$$ \left|\sum_{x \in \mathbb F_q }\psi( a_i x_i^d)\right| \leq q^{1-1/n}$$

The Weil bound gives the estimate:

$$\left|\sum_{x \in \mathbb F_q }\psi( a_i x_i^d)\right| \leq (d-1) \sqrt{q}$$

so for $d  \leq q^{1/2-1/n}$ we win.

This can be improved when $q$ is prime using better estimates for character sums, e.g. Estimates for the number of sums and products and for exponential sums in fields of prime order by Bourgain, Gibichuk, and Konyagin.

However I suspect that the Gauss sum method is not optimal. For $q$ a perfect square and $d= \sqrt{q}+1$, say, there is no cancellation in the Gauss sums, but still for $n=3$ we get a nontrivial solution by linear algebra over $\mathbb F_{q^{1/2}}$.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add to Will Sawin's answer and then mention two other results that are not as well known as they should be.

Regarding Sawin's method, this is worked out in great detail in Ireland and Rosen's text "A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory" in the Springer Graduate Texts in Mathematics series, Volume 84.  See Chapters 8 and 10 in particular.  This text also contains lots of references to previous work using this idea. One can also consult Wolfgang Schmidt's "Equations over Finite Fields", in the Springer Lecture Notes in Mathematics series, Volume 536.

Using other methods, the bound in Chevalley's theorem can be improved for diagonal homogeneous forms. Here are two very nice theorems due to Aimo Tietäväinen.

Theorem 1.
Let $p$ be a prime and let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be the finite field with
$q =p^d$ elements and let $f = a_1 x_1^k + \cdots + a_n x_n^k$ where each
$a_i \in \mathbb{F}_q^{\times}$.
Exclude the case $k = p-1$ and $d = 1$.  If $n \ge (k+3)/2$, then $f$ has
a nontrivial zero defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

This is proved in "On diagonal forms over finite fields" by Aimo Tietäväinen in
Ann. Univ. Turku. Ser. A I 118 (1968).

Note that Chevalley's theorem requires that $n \ge k+1$ and that the above
theorem would be false if $p$ is odd, $k = p-1$, and $d = 1$ by considering the
form $x_1^{p-1} + \cdots + x_{p-1}^{p-1}$.

The next theorem applies to diagonal forms that satisfy an additional hypothesis.  Let $f$ be a diagonal form as above.  Without loss of generality, we may assume that $k \mid q-1$.

Theorem 2.
Suppose that $f = a_1 x_1^k + \cdots + a_n x_n^k$ where $k \mid q-1$.
If $q$ is odd, assume in addition that $k \mid (q-1)/2$.  If $k \ge 3$ and
$n \ge 2\log_2(k-1) + 2$, then $f$ has a nontrivial zero defined
over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

This is proved in
Aimo Tietäväinen,
"On the non-trivial solvability of some equations and systems of equations in finite fields", Ann. Acad. Sci. Fenn. Ser. A I360(1965).

This second paper contains many more results and also considers the case of systems of diagonalized homogeneous forms over finite fields.

Comment: Since you're mentioning references, perhaps the most notable paper using the Fourier transform to count points on diagonal hypersurfaces is Weil's paper "Numbers of solutions of equations in finite fields", where he wrote down the Weil conjectures.